# How to clear a session without clearing other parts of the site

Tags: php, session

Difficult to explain this but here goes. I found a similar question in the search but it was for C, not PHP.

I am developing a PHP site which has two logged-in sections, one for employees and one for employers. When either user logs out, their session is cleared, at the moment with "session_destroy()". I also use that at the login page to clear any previous session.

The problem comes if I am working on both sections at the same time. Because they are on the same "site", logging into one logs out of the other. I am forced to use two browsers at a time, one logged into one section and the other into the other.

Is there a better way to end a session when a user logs out rather than "session_destroy()", something that won't affect the other part of the site?

Comment: U can just clear the logged in flag accordingly : ex. `unset($_SESSION['logged_in_as_member']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save each site's session data in a different part of the session:

```
$_SESSION['site1'] = ... ; 
$_SESSION['site2'] = ... ;
```

and then call unset on the session you don't want any more:

```
unset($_SESSION['site1']);
```

Answer (score 2):

you unset a specific session

```
     unset($_SESSION['variable']);
```

variable will be the user/admin session value